# Windows 10 will not forget network drive passwords. No standard solutions seem to work

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, network-shares

I'm still automatically connected when I restart the computer.

Commands like `use * /del` and `net use * /d /y` just return "There are no entries in the list"  (and "net use" returns an empty list).

In control panel, UserAccounts->Credential Manager->Windows Credentials doesn't list any of my drives though I deleted all entries anyway (with no effect).

Tried running `rundll32.exe keymgr.dll,KRShowKeyMgr` but it also showed an empty list.

Command `cmdkey /list` returns one entry (something like this also showed up in the windows credential manager and is evidently part of 'Windows Live Essentials' utilities):

```
Target: MicrosoftAccount:target=SSO_POP_Device
Type: Domain Extended Credentials
User: 02yocsmojsll
Saved for this logon only
```

Comment: Is it possible a login script or group policy is adding them back?

Comment: have you checked Credential Manager?

Comment: Reality check: Are the credentials required by the remote system the *same* as those used to logon the local machine? If so, connections to the remote machine will succeed despite no credentials being "saved."